# Model get 97% accuracy on train and validation but when use custom predict it get wrong

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use a CNN model to train image classification , it got great accuracy at test and validation (98% and 97%), but when use my image to predict it alway go wrong, here is my code:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 30
IMG_HEIGHT = 256
IMG_WIDTH = 256
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = np.ceil(image_count/BATCH_SIZE)

train_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=str(data_dir),
                                                     batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                     shuffle=True,
                                                     target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                     classes = list(CLASS_NAMES))
```

here is prepare for dataset and data argumentation:

```
imgDataGen=ImageDataGenerator(
    validation_split=0.2,
    rescale=1/255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    zoom_range=0.3,
    rotation_range=15.,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
)
```

prepare data:

```
train_dataset = imgDataGen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=str(data_dir),
    target_size = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), 
    classes = list(CLASS_NAMES),
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
    subset = 'training'
)

val_dataset = imgDataGen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=str(data_dir),
    target_size = (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), 
    classes = list(CLASS_NAMES),
    batch_size =BATCH_SIZE,
    subset = 'validation'
)
```

the model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='sigmoid'))
```

complie:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001,momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['acc'])
```

train

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_dataset, 
    validation_data = val_dataset,
    workers=10,
    epochs=20,
)
```

It get pretty high accuracy **98% on test and 97% on validation**

but when i try with my code to predict

```
def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE=256
    img_array=cv2.imread(filepath)
    new_array= cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)
model=tf.keras.models.load_model('trained-model.h5',compile=False)

#np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':'{:f}'.format})
predict=model.predict([prepare('cat.jpg')])
pred_name = CATEGORIES[np.argmax(predict)]
print(pred_name)
```

it got wrong, with cat image it go for dog and dog for cat, but sometime it go right, just i think 98% is more accurate than this, if i try 5 image of cats it fail 3 or 4 images

so it because dataset or because of code? 
please help, thanks

Comment: do you normalize that image before passing it thorugh the net, like you normalized the training data (/255)?

Comment: What is normalize data? Im totally new to this, and what is it benefit?

Answer (score 0):

So in your second code-block you have this:

```
rescale=1/255
```

This is for normalizing your image into the range [0;1]. So every image gets rescaled (/normalized) before going through the network. But in you las code-block where you test it on an image you didnt add normalization. Try adding that to your "prepare" function:

```
def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 256
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath)

    # add this:
    img_array = image_array / 255

    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)
```

Comment: hey i tried this, but when not `/255` it get dog(still error for cat pic) but add `/255` it return car :((